# How to get only required columns in Python script while parsing the data from Json File

Tags: python, arrays, json, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to write a python script . As per the requirement I have around 400 columns which will be coming as per of multiple arrays in JSON file.

I am using Pandas library and python version 3.6. I may get more columns than 400 column from the JSON file. How can i restrict the unwanted columns and I want to get only specified columns in my python output file.

I am using below code to get the data  as per specified columns.

Issue: In my output file other than mentioned columns in the column list file I am also getting the rest of the columns. How can I restrict the unwanted columns and get only required columns in my output?

```
with open('Columns.txt') as c:
    columns_list = c.readlines()
    with open('JsonFile.json') as f:
    json_file = json.load(f)

    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns_list)
```

and i have one more scneario.. Currently i have data as below sample data.

70 % of cases i have data like [attributes][ABC][Values][Value] and in remaining  cases i have [attributes][Xdfghgjgjgj][grp]( here i have some 2 records inside ) . To handle these type of scenario multi valued attributes can you help me with some solution

```
{
  "entities": [
    {
      "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
       "data": {
        "attributes": {
          "ABC": {
            "values": [
              {
                "value": 00000000000000
              }
            ]
          }
          "Xdfghgjgjgj": {
            "grp": [
              {
                "SUPP": {
                  "values": [
                    {
                      "value": "000000000000000000"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "yfyfyfyfyfy": {
                  "values": [
                    {
                      "value": "909000090099090"
                    }
                  ]
                },
              },
              {
                "SUPP": {
                  "values": [
                    {
                      "value": "000000000000000000"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "yfyfyfyfyfy": {
                  "values": [
                    {
                      "value": "909000090099090"
                    }
                  ]
                },
              }
            ]
          }
          }
```

Comment: so basicly you want to select columns by name and store them in the output file ?

Comment: @nassim: Yes Nassim. I may have "n" number of attributes in Json file. But in the final output whatever columns are required i want to keep them in one file and get only those attributes values and if they are not available then nulls. But in my code along with the specified attributes ,  i am also getting rest of the attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a way to read specific columns from csv using pandas :

```
import pandas as pd
cols= ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']

df = pd.read_csv('JsonFile.csv', skipinitialspace=True, usecols=cols)

#save to output
df.to_csv('output.csv',Index=False)
```

or you could specify the columns when you are saving your file :

```
df = pd.read_csv('JsonFile.csv')
df[column_names].to_csv('output.csv',index=False)
```

Edit :

```
with open('Columns.txt') as c:
    columns_list = c.readlines()
with open('JsonFile.json') as f:
    json_file = json.load(f)

#df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_file, orient='columns')
df = pd.DataFrame(json_file)
df[columns_list].to_csv('output.csv',index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks Nassim but i have source file as ****.json ( json file ) and while i am creating my output csv files then i want to consider only attributes which are required ( These required columns as i have some aound 400 columns so i have saved in a text file and i am reading them )..

Comment: sorry i didn't see the format, i updated my answer accordingly. Please give it a try and tell me if it doesn't work

Comment: Worked. I just tried with simply adding [columns_list]  like df[columns_list] and it worked ...

Comment: Thanks a lot. .. I need one more suggestion.. can i ask here ?

Comment: i added the question at the top with 2nd scenario  ,please help me with your suggestion